# Correct schema for multiple one to many relationships?

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

I'm trying to figure out how to properly create several one-to-many relationships for one row in the database.

Say I have a product table.

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
`productID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`productName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`productID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The product can have a one-to-one category relationship or one-to-many.

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
`categoryID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`categoryName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`categoryID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I've created a lookup table with foreign keys, but I don't think it's going to work because there can be products which are associated with various different category groups.

```
CREATE TABLE `category_to_product` (
`categoryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`productID` int(11) NOT NULL,
KEY `categoryID` (`categoryID`),
KEY `productID` (`productID`),
CONSTRAINT `category_to_product_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`productID`) 
REFERENCES `product` (`productID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `category_to_product_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`categoryID`) 
REFERENCES `category` (`categoryID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**EDIT**

---

The queries in my database are based on levels and each higher level of query is dependent on the previous level. level 1 would be a base level query, and would contain the most general information, lets say this category is electronics.

The level 2 query, would be a slightly more refined query and would be a sub-category of electronics so something like electronics->televisions. *Think of it as a breadcrumb.* This seems difficult in itself to do, but in this case, the product needs to be able to relate to several different category *groups* which can contain the same level or different levels. I hope this makes sense.

---

How would I structure my database for this type of relationship? Initially I had the category levels separated under different columns in the lookup table, which worked nicely but there were too many NULL values.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. First of all, this is not a one-to-many relationship but a many-to-many one (product 1 can have many categories; category red can have many products). Your approach looks good. Only replace `KEY categoryID (categoryID), KEY productID (productID)` with a combined primary key `PRIMARY KEY (productID, categoryID)`. What is your question/problem actually?

Comment: After researching more on how to do this, it occurred to me that the model I need is similar to a hierarchy which looks like a mess to manage in MYSQL. I will be updating the question with a clearer explanation and diagram soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is very generic. A product doesn't have any fixed attribute in your model (except its name), but has a set of optional associated attributes. So there can be trousers of unknown color and material. Or a computer made of cotton and trousers made of tin. An Xbox mirror with twenty colors and a bike that is both leightweight and heavyweight.

You don't even see that red and green are colors and plastic and metal are materials.

So you must start from scratch: What do you actually need? Aren't there product groups like "computer" and "washing machine"? Then each group could have mandatory attributes like cpu for a computer and energy class for a washing machine, and optional attributes like the color maybe, which can be given but is not considered necessary, or like screen for the computer, which it may have or not. Then each product would belong to a product group and you'd know what attributes can or must be entered for it (and by which attributes you can filter certain products).

Then think about what attributes you have:

- cpu = Intel i5| Intel i7|AMD FX = a list of possible values for the one cpu
- color = white | black | ... = also a list, but there can be more than one color per product
- mouse = yes | no = a boolean flag
- modelno = ____ = free text attributes

And then think of an appropriate table design for these.

If you even want hierarchic attributes like color = luminous bright orange => bright orange => orange (so one can search for all orange products or just light orange products or even just luminous bright orange products), then you need some structure for that, too. But then: Shouldn't one be able to also look for luminous orange products, as well, or for any light color products? Then this would no longer be a hierarchic tree.

As you see this all can become quite complicated. Think about what you really need. Make it as complicated as needed, but only as complicated as that.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. You've helped me realize that I need a better structure that will be more versatile. I do have product groups, it's just a matter of finding a common relation between them. But "tin trousers" will definitely not be an option!

Answer (score 0):

Your example dictates a third table, but first you need to add a primary key to your category_to_product_table(* `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT)

Third table for the groups:

CREATE TABLE `category_to_product_groups` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`categoryProductGroupName` varchar(40),
`category_to_product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

This third table will have multiple rows per group names(and a group could simply be one or more category_to_product rows).

Comment: This is the dilemma I have, I need to keep the categories separated. The problem with a groups table is that every row in the product table would have a different group.

Comment: Why would the groups need to be different?  I would eliminate the options to create the CONSTRAINTS and REFS if that's what's holding you back.  Make your schema flexible and do your delete's and references through your scripting language (python,php,etc) if possible.  Let me know if I'm missing the point here.

Comment: The categories have to be separate because each product may relate to them.

Comment: @Anthony Manzo: I don't see any need for an additional ID here. Why do you think it is needed?

Comment: @EternalHour: What do you mean with separated categories? You have categories, products and the relation between the two. What else do you need?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I have updated the question, I hope it makes more sense